# How I can resolve the MariaDB problem in SQL in my query?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I use Jupiter notebook with python for using sql so

i have the next error:

> ```
> ': (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE AllPoints > 30000' at line 11")
> ```

and

i have this query

```
query = '''SELECT players.playerID, lastName, SUM(points) AS AllPoints

    FROM players

    JOIN players_teams
    ON players.playerID = players_teams.playerID
    
    
    GROUP BY lastName, players.playerID
    
    WHERE AllPoints > 30000
    '''
puntos = pd.read_sql(query,db)
puntos
```

I think it is a simple query so I don t know where it is the error.

thanks for helping

Comment: `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Get familiar with the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't use WHERE after GROUP BY but you can use HAVING. Your query should be :

```
SELECT 
  players.playerID, lastName, SUM(points) AS AllPoints
FROM 
  players
  INNER JOIN players_teams ON players.playerID = players_teams.playerID  
GROUP BY 
  players.playerID   
HAVING SUM(points) > 30000
```

Comment: oh thank you, I don t remember this rule

Comment: and why you use INNER JOIN instead of ON?

Comment: JOIN = INNER JOIN , but it will be more clear in future if someone else going to modify the query.